# SelectionChanged on ListView inside ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm new at WPF and programming in general, so I'm having an issue selecting an item from a ListView that is placed inside another ListView. I'm using the SelectionChanged event to try and solve this issue. 
When SelectionChanged is placed in the outer ListView the event is raised, however it won't be raised when the event is in the inner ListView.

Here is the XAML code for the ListView (In the example the SelectionChanged event is placed in the inner ListView):

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Mechanics, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="auto" Width="1330" 
             Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="13" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FFF2F2F2">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="18"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="22"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1200"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="{Binding MecID}" Grid.Column="0" Padding="0" FontSize="11" Background="#FFF2F2F2"/>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1" Padding="0" FontSize="11" Margin="2, 0, 0, 0"/>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MecJobs, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0, -18, 0, 0" Height="18" Width="1200" Grid.Column="2" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="White" SelectionChanged="OpenJob" SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.CurrentJob, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0"></StackPanel>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Canvas>
                                    <ListViewItem Width="{Binding EstimatedTimeWidth}" Canvas.Left="{Binding Margin}" Background="{Binding Color}" Height="18" 
                                               Padding="0" Margin="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                                        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Height="18" Padding="0" Margin="0">
                                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                                                    <Binding Path="RegNumber" />
                                                    <Binding Path="CustomerName" />
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </TextBlock.Text>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </ListViewItem>
                                </Canvas>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

I hope someone has a good advice

Comment: You have to give the data context of the inner list view as well through relative source find ancestor and then it will get raised.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion. However, when i add: RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}} to the inner ListView it won't display any of the content when I run the application. Isn't this what you meant with your comment?

Comment: The RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView} instead of Window.
The visual tree comes into picture here, if you want to find the Window then you have to add the following:
RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}
Mode=FindAncestor is important to find a parent control.

Comment: I've tried both suggestions. However, when I add the lines to the inner ListView for the MecJobs, then the application won't run. There is no errors, it just doesn't start.